# how to access primavera P6 web services using python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, primavera

I need to build a dynamic service to access P6 data using P6 exposed web services using Python, it is currently done using .net in our project but we want to do it in Python.

How do We authenticate and connect to those service using Python instead?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you had any luck trying to do this? I am able to create a Bearer Token via the Rest API, but when sending get request with bearer I get 401 returned.  It also suggests that I am not logged in and to provide a session cookie.